# Strings are appearing in uppercase in Windows Phone 8 with Cordova

Tags: windows-phone-8, cordova

I am developing an application for Windows Phone 8 with Cordova.

My problem is that strings are displayed in upper case (e.g. `india` is being displayed as `INDIA`).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you began your work on the new app by extending the template onwards. That's a valid strategy, but the template's CSS styles include the following rule:

```
body {
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

That effectively causes everything to show in upper case.